# How can i show a submenu element of a navigation menu on top of a horizontall scrolling bar using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have created a navigation menu which has many elements and i made it scrolling horizontally for more user experience. The menu is located inside of a container fit to the browser screen. Now on the menu items that have submenus on hover the dropdown elements are showing inside the navigation container an not on top of it even i have increased the `z-index`. How can i fix my code ?

**This is my actual code:**

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .custom-container {
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
      }

      ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        overflow-y: none;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #333;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
      }

      li {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        background-color: #333;
        position: relative;
      }

      li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
      }

      .active {
        background-color: #04aa6d;
      }

      .submenu {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #333;
        width: 200px;
        z-index: 3;
        left: 0;
        top: calc(100% + 10px);
      }

      li:hover .submenu {
        display: block;
      }

      .submenu a {
        padding: 8px 16px;
      }
      ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 5px;
      }

      ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgb(255 255 255);
        border-radius: 5px;
      }

      ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #00ce9d;
      }

      ::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
        height: 5px;
        background-color: white;
      }
      ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #00ce9d;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="custom-container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#news">News</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Current Behavior:**
[image]

**Desired Behavior:**

The submenu items must be on top of the horizontall scroll:

[image]

Comment: I think you might need a solution like this one here, https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: @AniketPandey That is my actual case. Please relate to the question above

Comment: I mistyped. I meant vertical-scroll. Also, you have so many z-indexes set and position properties which do not do anything. also, if `.custom-container` is a div by default it's `width:100%;`, no need to set it manually. I would suggest you clean your code and then edit the question.

Comment: @AniketPandey if you have a valid solution please feel free to submit your answer than i will be happy to mark as solved in case it solves the issue. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Bro, Actually there was unexpected result because of css overflow on parent, and z-index property cant solve this here. I change 2 lies only in css.
Please check if this works for you.

```css
.custom-container {
          width: 100%;
          overflow-x: visible;
          position: relative;
          z-index: 1;
        }
  
        ul {
          display: flex;
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          overflow-y: none;
          padding: 0;
          background-color: #333;
          white-space: nowrap;
          position: relative;
          z-index: 2;
        }
  
        li {
          flex: 0 0 auto;
          background-color: #333;
          position: relative;
        }
  
        li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
  
        li a:hover:not(.active) {
          background-color: #111;
        }
  
        .active {
          background-color: #04aa6d;
        }
  
        .submenu {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #333;
          width: 200px;
          z-index: 3;
          left: 0;
          top: 100%;
        }
  
        li:hover .submenu {
          display: block;
        }
  
        .submenu a {
          padding: 8px 16px;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
          width: 5px;
        }
  
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
          -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgb(255 255 255);
          border-radius: 5px;
        }
  
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
          border-radius: 5px;
          background: #00ce9d;
        }
  
        ::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
          height: 5px;
          background-color: white;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
          border-radius: 5px;
          background: #00ce9d;
        }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="custom-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <div class="submenu">
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
              <a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: No. The menu needs to be fit to the screen so it must be scrollable horizontally inside the container. That is the purpose of having the submenu on top of the scrolling bar